# Symbology of a point layer on attributes of a child layer

Tags: qgis

I have created a project in which I want to monitor technical systems. The systems are serviced at different annual intervals. I have created a point layer that shows the plant locations and contains the main information about the plant. I would like to keep the maintenance dates in a child layer (without geometry). The relationship between parent and child layer runs through the ID.

In order to quickly get an overview of which systems have already been checked in the current year, I would like to color the point layer (= parent) based on the features from the child layer, for example green (if the system has already been checked).

I've already written about 4 hours with the expression-editor in different ways today, but I can't find a way to do create this connection.

Comment: Moin Julian, bitte poste deine Frage auf Englisch, damit alle Nutzer a) die Frage lesen & verstehen, b) beantworten, und c) die Antwort später auch für sich selbst nutzen können. danke. - Hi Julian, please post your question in English in order to allow all users to participate, thank you.

Comment: Also, please provide example data and what you tried so far based on that data.